# Historical reference request on Nilpotent groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, ho.history-overview

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Historical_remarks):

"**Abelian groups** were named after Norwegian mathematician Niels Henrik Abel by Camille Jordan because Abel found that the commutativity of the group of a polynomial implies that the roots of the polynomial can be calculated by using radicals"

From [Wikipedia's article on solvable groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group):

"Historically, the word **solvable** arose from Galois theory and the proof of the general unsolvability of quintic equation."

> **Question.** Where do **nilpotent groups** come from ? Who defined them first ? For what purpose ? Any reference ?

Comment: btw the original French word for solvable was *résoluble* and has two English translations in use: the most common *solvable* and also *soluble*

Comment: Isn't there one which is more British English and the other American English ?

Comment: possibly. Maybe it also depends on the subcommunauties of people working with groups. I especially saw "soluble" among the British community of combinatorial group theory.

Comment: Yes soluble is more usual in British and solvable in America although, despite being British, I prefer solvable myself. I associate soluble more with chemistry (salt is soluble in water).

Comment: It's not named after Niels Nilpotent. The term “nilpotent group” is based on an analogy with ring theory. In a ring, an element with a power equal to 0 is called nilpotent.  In a Lie
algebra $\mathfrak g$, an element $x$ could be called nilpotent if the linear operator $y \mapsto [x, y]$ on $\mathfrak g$ is
nilpotent in the sense of ring theory (a power of the operator is 0). By a theorem of Engel, all elements of a Lie algebra are nilpotent if and only if the Lie group corresponding to the Lie algebra has the property we call being a nilpotent group.

Comment: I hadn't thought of Niels A., I would have tried H. Fitting ! Nil- from Latin 'nihil' which means "nothing", "rien" in French ; and '-potent' from 'potere', meaning 'to be able to', 'pouvoir' in French (which also means 'power').

Comment: This post seems to be better suited to [hsm.se], since it mainly historical in nature.

Comment: Here's what the Oxford ED says: Late 19th century: from nil + Latin potens, potent- 'power'.

Comment: @zeno: as far as I remember, potens is the '-ing' form of the verb potere ; what is power ? the faculty of being able to. 'Potent' litteraly means 'they can' to me. Maybe a true Latinist would have a better/another interpretation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 1870, the American mathematician, **Benjamin Pierce** first introduced the term ***nilpotent*** in the context of his work on the classification of Algebras. In Algebra, an element $x$ of a ring $R$ is said to be nilpotent if there exists some positive integer $n$ such that $x^{n}=0$.

In group theory, a nilpotent group is a group having a special property that makes it 'almost abelian' through repeated application of the commutator operation defined by $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$

For justification of the term nilpotent, start with a nilpotent group $G$ and an element $g$ of $G$ and define a function $ f : G \longrightarrow G $ by $f(x) = [x, g] = xgx^{-1}g^{-1}$. This function is sometimes referred to as being the adjoint action. Then this function is nilpotent in the sense that there exists a natural number $n$ such that $f^{n}$, the $n$-th iteration of $f$ sends every element $x$ of $G$ to the identity element.

Comment: The spelling is "Peirce" (and the prononciation is the same as in "terse", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Peirce)

Answer (score 2):

The group theoretic term nilpotent is simply a transfer from Lie theory: A Lie algebra is nilpotent if $\text{ad}\,x$ is nilpotent for all $x$ (Engel's theorem). Then a connected Lie group is nilpotent if its Lie algebra is nilpotent. Finally, the characterization with upper/lower central series generalized to all groups yielding nilpotent groups in general.